# How can I position my iPad so I can effortlessly watch a movie in bed?

Tags: ipad

My TV sits right there in the corner, it's kinda lazy and perfect. But I haven't figured out how to passively enjoy my iPad. I am now bending my knees up and propping it against my thighs. But I can't fall asleep like this and that's what I want to do when I enjoy a movie in bed. How can I position my iPad so I can effortlessly watch a movie in bed?

Comment: It really depends on what your favourite position to sleep in is. What is it? Also, I feel like this is off topic somehow, but not sure how.

Comment: Tape it to the ceiling, for a more permanent fixture use super glue!

Comment: This isn't a great question, but it's on topic. It is personal and subjective, but this isn't really a question that will lend itself to excessive discussion or argument (the other half of the criteria for closing a subjective question)

Comment: I understand your concerns about the subjectivity of this question. But it is a real question, and one I imagine asked by others with similar, generally human sleeping patterns and behaviors. Using an iPad in bed seems to me (a new iPad owner) a very active endeavor. How can I make it more passive?

Comment: This question is fine, it may not be similar to most of the other questions on this site but it's just a person asking for advice. Upvoted to counter all these downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Lay on your side with the iPad on a bedside table or on the other side of a bed.

Get an Apple TV and stream the content to the TV.

Answer (score 2):

Get a cat. I find the best way to use my iPad in bed is to put the cat on my lap, pat him and give him attention for a few minutes and then he is perfectly happy to be used as an iPad stand until I'm ready for sleep.

He's quite flexible so easily moved around till the iPad is in the right position.

Highly recommended. Oh, long haired breeds are better - they have all that hair on their bellies that protect the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some kind of iPad stand and one of those bed-trays, you could use the stand to prop up the iPad on that.

Alternatively, you could just hook it up to a TV/screen using Apple's adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Get a "boom" microphone stand from SamAsh, Guitar Center, or any other large music equipment store.  Then get one of the many iPad mic stand holders now available. My fave is TheGigEasy...2nd choice: iClip.

Position it (with iPad attached) as far over the bed as possible while the stand is on the side (or behind the head of) your bed.  Keep in mind that the weight of the iPad will cause the stand to tip if you position the boom too far over.  The only solution to this is weight(s) placed on the foot/pedestal of the stand.  I'm able to get it about 1/3 of the way over the bed...then I adjust for height, and simply read while lying down.  It's great.

Answer (score 1):

Take some fishing line, run it through your case in such a way to provide the right view angle. Use a thumb tack and suspend it from the ceiling. Win.

Answer (score 1):

There was a paper carton product in eBay called bookUp. It is from Korea. I bought PVC pipes and created a frame.  It now lasted 3 years and going strong.

This is the best hands down.

Comment: Any chance you can post pics?

Answer (score 1):

I mainly read but either watching a movie or reading. I find laying on my side with the iPad propped up against another pillow or wall so I can orientate it to match my natural viewing angle and not have to hold is the most comfortable. Also I find can fall asleep this way also.

[image]